# CSH and all output (with errors) to file

Tags: io-redirection, csh, stderr

I need save all output from compilation to file. I have many errors `undefined reference` and I want see all of these errors.
I try `makeall >& out`, but in file `out` aren't any of error `undefined reference`.

I must use `csh` to run `makeall`.

Comment: Works for me. Did you get any output to the screen from your `makeall >&out` command?

Comment: Yes. When I try "makeall >& out" I get errors on screen (only errors).

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `csh`? In `csh` `>&` will redirect both stdout and stderr, but in Bourne shells it will redirect just stderr.

Comment: Hmm, I tryied to make bad main.cpp and I tried to compile it "g++ main.cpp >& out". Errors from this are in out. My $SHELL is /bin/csh. Maybe script makeall do something strange and csh can't redirect some of output to file.

Comment: Can you add the `makeall` script to your question? Or is it either commercially confidential or way too long to do so?

Comment: It's too long and confidential too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `makeall |& tee out`? This should still print everything on screen, but also in the file `out`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it appears that the obvious solutions are not working. Please could you try this, `sh -c 'makeall >out 2>&1'` (you may need to amend the `makeall` part to include the full path, or append various flags; just make sure that it's all inside the single quotes).

If it produces an error please provide that here.

If no error but you still don't get your compilation errors in the out file then your `makeall` script is almost certainly doing something very strange with the *stdout* and *stderr* file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

If your `makeall` script itself redirects stderr to the terminal device or to `/dev/tty`, no amount of redirecting `makeall`'s stderr will help.

Since redirection support in csh is very limited compared to Bourne-like or rc-like shells, it's not uncommon to see things like:

```
cmd >& /dev/null > /dev/tty
```

To redirect only stderr (while redirecting `stdout` to the tty assuming it was what it was before).

Or:

```
(cmd1; cmd2 >& /dev/tty; cmd3) >& file.log
```

For `cmd2` to be exempt from the redirection to the log file.

Now, since the redirection there is made explicitly to `/dev/tty`, our only option, is to make that `/dev/tty` go to your `out` file.

For that, you could use a pseudo-terminal which you'd make the stdout and stderr of your `makeall` command.

For that, you could use `script`. With the implementations from `util-linux` at least:

```
script -qec 'stty raw -echo; exec makeall' out >& /dev/null
```

Replace the `>& /dev/null` with `< /dev/null` (to avoid `script` putting the host terminal in raw mode as well) to also see the output+errors (in addition to it being logged in the `out` file).